# Removing Hacked URL Strings From Google

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I recently suffered a hack on a number of websites which were hosted on the same server. I've identified and removed the source of the hack, and used [Patrick Altoft's](http://www.blogstorm.co.uk/how-to-use-google-alerts-to-find-out-if-your-site-gets-hacked/) smart Google Alerts idea to monitor for further attempts.

I've then logged into Google webmaster tools, asked to be re-evaluated post hack, and I've also re-submitted site maps to speed up a re-crawl.

However I would like to remove the infected url's from Google, and was thinking the best way to speed up this process would be to use .htaccess to return a 404 error, whenever a page with a specific string variable appeared.

Is this possible with a .htaccess file, or is there a better course of action to take?

You can see the damage done [here](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&q=approval%20OR%20sex%20OR%20cash%20OR%20loan%20OR%20viagra%20OR%20cialis%20OR%20levitra%20OR%20Phentermine%20OR%20Xanax%20site%3awww.spinnekoppen.com&lr=lang_en).

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Comment: You've probably already found this ...but just for completeness' sake: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=164734

Comment: Cheers, yeah I found that, but there's something like 700 infected URL's, so removing them one by one would be laborious. What I need is a way of telling Google that any URL with a string which includes yuboke is to be removed, and unless I've missed it, Google doesn't allow for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

404 will work, but is possible not the best solution. A better solution would be 301: moved permanently, or 410: gone.

A 404 tells you that a page is missing, but not why. Google may keep these urls for a while to investigate later whether they exist again. By using 301 or 410, you explicitly tell Google that that url is not going to be fixed.

410 is the better option, but I'm not sure if this is possible from htaccess, athough you could 301 to a php-file that returns a 410 header.

Addition: Here's an article about redirecting using the '410, Gone' header with .htaccess. http://diveintomark.org/archives/2003/03/27/http_error_410_gone

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll probably give that a go, if I can figure out how to write such a file. :)

Comment: Here's an article about redirecting using the '410, Gone' header with .htaccess. http://diveintomark.org/archives/2003/03/27/http_error_410_gone

Comment: The final .htaccess file which fixed the problem is:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)yuboke(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [G]

Answer (score 1):

Yep, give them 404/410/301 status code, then Google will remove them in a day or two. I've done that before. It will take way too long for Google to renew its cache with 200 status code.

Comment: Cheers for the response. How do you go about doing that though? As I say, there's something like 700 infected URL's, what's the best way of delivering a 404 status code for that many URL's?

Comment: Like you said, use .htaccess to redirect them to a location that does not exist, or to a php script where you can set http header manually.